# Is there a restriction on alcoholic drinks in an emergency exit seat?

Tags: air-travel, seating, alcohol, emergencies

While booking a chargeable seat with extra space, alongside emergency exit, the airline (Air India) is asking to agree to terms and conditions that include:

> Not be under the influence of any intoxicating substance at check-in, boarding, and during the flight.

This makes sense but then this also might mean that the airline may not serve liquor to people sitting on seats in the emergency exit rows. However, I have never seen this happen before.

So can we say if this is this specific to airlines and is at the discretion of the airline?

Comment: Certainly it would fall under be capable of following instructions.  But were these additional terms just for the exit row? Or are they general terms for the airline.  Because the "check-in" and "boarding" clauses would be irrelevant for someone who may or may not end up in an exit row (EG seat allocation could get swapped after boarding - I've personally seen this happen for exit rows).

Comment: Yes, just for seats with extra leg space which are alongside emergency exit. So effectively we pay more but then if alcohol is not served then it seems a bit odd.

Comment: My guess is that this just means you can't be "drunk," not that you can't have a drink.

Comment: Some airlines manage the risk of passengers over-indulging on long haul by limiting the serving of alcohol to meal times only, I don’t think I’ve ever seen them not serve it to those in emergency exit seats

Comment: In my experience, rules for exit row passengers and their enforcement vary **a lot** from one airline to the other. Some will check early on (during check-in or at the gate) that the passenger is actually "suitable", brief them, ask for consent, and re-seat them if things don't work out. IIRC most often in the US, probably on airlines that have been burned by previous lawsuits. Airlines at the other end of the scale will just include a few words in the safety briefing. And you'll find about anything in between. So policies about serving alcohol and how much probably vary a lot as well.

Comment: @jcaron I've regularly been asked for consent when seated in an exit row, and the have been told that I need to verbalize my consent, and that just nodding my head is not sufficient.

Comment: Another weird rule I've run into is that you can't sit in the exit row if you need a seatbelt extender. Since I often need this I never sit there. Luckily I'm short so I don't need the extra legroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any airline with a policy restricting alcoholic drinks in an emergency exit seat beyond the generic "[don't be](https://image.koreanair.com/sms/exit-popup-en.html) under the influence of alcohol, medication and so forth", and it's up to the flight attendant to decide how to implement it. In practice it's highly unlikely one gets restricted unless becoming a problem not specific to the exit row. [Some airlines](https://redd.it/18bjvwu) such as [AA](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/experience/seats/main-cabin-extra.jsp) even give free alcoholic drinks to exit row passengers, since such rows are sometimes marketed as premium.